# Doctrine2 The association mapping 'ManyToMany' misses the 'targetEntity' attribute. Exception

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

I want to create three tables use symfony2 and doctrine. Firm , Category and CategoryRelation. This two table have manyToMany relation , i will this relations keep in categoryRelation table. My yml mapping is;

```
Firm:
// other columns
  ManyToMany:
    categories:
      targetEntity: Category
      joinTable:
        name: category_relation
        joinColumns:
          firm_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          category_id:
            referencedColumnName: id


Category:
 // other columns
  manyToMany:
    firms:
    targetEntity: Firm
    mappedBy: categories
```

and give me this error

```
The association mapping 'ManyToMany' misses the 'targetEntity' attribute.
```

How can I resolve this error? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

I compared your code with the example code of http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html, section 5.14. Many-To-Many, Bidirectional. I paste that code below:

```
User:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    groups:
      targetEntity: Group
      inversedBy: users
      joinTable:
        name: users_groups
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          group_id:
            referencedColumnName: id

Group:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    users:
      targetEntity: User
      mappedBy: groups
```

I've seen some differences which could produce that Exception. Firstly, you doesn't write the type: entity directive. Your first manyToMany directive has the first M in capital letter. The inversedBy directive doesn't exist. And finally I think this is the main problem, your directives targetEntity and mappedBy are not indented:

```
firms:
targetEntity: Firm
mappedBy: categories
```

And YAML is based on the indentation, therefore, probably this is the targetEntity specified  in the Exception. You should write it in this way:

```
firms:
    targetEntity: Firm
    mappedBy: categories
```